# Bash command: is it possible to pass an argument before a custom command (function) or it must be only after:

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, function

I am wondering if it is possible to pass an argument to a custom command before the command?

Let say I have custom command `ping` and I would like to pass the IP address before command:

instead `ping 1.1.1.1` to be `1.1.1.1 ping`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `addr='1.1.1.1' ; ping "$addr"` ?

Comment: `echo "1.1.1.1" | xargs ping` ?

Comment: How is the shell to understand that you're not trying to run the command `1.1.1.1` with argument `ping`? So no, not directly like that.

Comment: I am just trying to see if I can build a custom function that will be able to recognize the IP address as entered first... I don't think it is possible with already build-in commands

Comment: @Costas: `ping() { command ping "$addr"; }; addr=1.1.1.1 ping`

Comment: @mikeserv Nice! I'd like it. What is the `command` purpose?

Comment: @Costas - so `ping()` calls `$PATH/ping` and not `ping()` recursively.

Comment: @mikeserv I see. Thanx for explanation. Further variant: `alias ping='ping $addr' ; addr=1.1.1.1 ; ping`

Comment: @Costas - That would work *(but you'd want to quote `$addr`)*, but it is a little different in some shells. In `bash`, `zsh` the `var=... fn` defines a variable local to the function - the function can play with it as much as it wants, but its value and definition disappears when the function returns. That behavior is explicitly contrary to standard, though. But there are some open bug reports filed with the Open Group on altering it. Personally, I prefer global behavior, as w/ your alias, but it would be better still if `fn()(:)` got locals and `fn(){ :; }` got globals, in my opinion.

Comment: @mikeserv The form `addr=1.1.1.1 ping` don't work in my `bash 4.3.11`. Everything what I can do to make variable local - use `()` form

Comment: @Costas - I dunno what you're doing, but: `bash -c 'ping(){ command ping "$addr"; }; addr=1.1.1.1 ping'
ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Is there any real reason for wanting to swap the command name and its argument(s)?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the example of `ping`:

```
echo 1.1.1.1 | xargs ping
```

Argument before command

Comment: Do I need to type `echo` before IP address in your example?

Comment: Of course. If you put 1.1.1.1 alone, the shell takes it as a command, generates an error and everything fails.

Answer (score -1):

This is a little cumbersome, but it seems to mostly work:

```
cmd_handler() {
    eval "cmd_words=($BASH_COMMAND)"
    last_word="${cmd_words[@]: -1:1}"
    if [ "$last_word" = gnip ]
    then
        argcm1=$((${#cmd_words[@]}-1))
        ping "${cmd_words[@]:0:$argcm1}"
        return 1
    fi
}
shopt -s extdebug
trap cmd_handler debug
```

The first ten lines, obviously, define a function called `cmd_handler`. 
The `trap cmd_handler debug` command specifies that
bash should call `cmd_handler` for every command you type. 
The command that you typed, e.g., `1.1.1.1 ping`,
is made available to the function in the `$BASH_COMMAND` variable. 
This is just a scalar string,
so we use `cmd_words=($BASH_COMMAND)` to split it into words. 
This would cause the hypothetical command

```
ls -l This is "Super User".
```

to be split into six words:

- `ls`
- `-l`
- `This`
- `is`
- `"Super`, and
- `User".`

so we use `eval` to make the shell interpret the quotes. 
The `${array_name[@]:offset:length}` construct
yields the *`length`* members of the array
beginning with `${array_name[offset]}`. 
An *`offset`* of -1 refers to the last element; so, as the name suggests,
this evaluates to the last word of the command. 
Include a space so it doesn’t look like you’re saying `…:-…`. 
If this is the name of your custom command
(which I’ve represented as `gnip` for testing purposes),
compute the argument count minus 1 (`argcm1`)
and execute `ping` with all the words except for the last as arguments. 
`return 1` to tell the shell not to try to handle this command through normal parsing.

I have found some glitches and some workarounds:

- Obviously, this will not handle `1.1.1.1 gnip -n 4 -w 500`.

  - It will handle `1.1.1.1 -n 4 -w 500 gnip`.
  - You could modify `cmd_handler`
    to check every word in the command line for the name of your custom command.
- `1.1.1.1 gnip > ping.out` won’t work,
  because `cmd_handler` will see `ping.out` as the last word. 
  You can use

  - `(1.1.1.1 gnip) > ping.out` or
  - `{ 1.1.1.1 gnip;} > ping.out`

  The first one will run the command in a subshell; the second one won’t. 
  Remember that the second form requires a space after the `{`
  and a semicolon (`;`) before the `}`.
- `1.1.1.1 gnip | some other command` won’t work,
  and I don’t understand why not.  You can work around this
  by saying `(1.1.1.1 gnip) > >(some other command)`,
  or use the other form, `{ 1.1.1.1 gnip;} > >(some other command)`,
  if you want your command to run in the main shell.

There are probably other pitfalls that I haven’t found yet.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will give a shot and let you know how it worked for me.